# Is this question a real question? Am I understanding the FAQ correctly?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

From my understanding of the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), this question is not a good question:
[How to query the average from a certain property in an Entity and return it in a List of List of objects in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071538/how-to-query-the-average-from-a-certain-property-in-an-entity-and-return-it-in-a)

Am I correct? It seems to me like the question by the OP doesn't show any effort towards solving his problem. He did put a ton of information in the question (although I think the way is written it is not that good, but that is personal opinion).

So under the "do your homework" assumption is a bad question. Am I right?

And what would it be the better thing to do in this case in case I am right? Should I ask in a comment what he has tried so far? If he doesn't answer flag the question as a not real question?

I feel that since the question has been answered already, it is probably worth to leave it open, as it may help other people in the use of group by in [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query). Would that be the best thing to do now? Leave the question open since can be helpful to others?

I am sorry if I am asking something very basic here. I am confused sometimes about how the rules for asking apply to questions.

I would appreciate any advice in this topic!

Comment: Seems to me he has a good (and accepted) answer.. So obviously someone understood enough to post a good answer.

Comment: _"So under the "do your homework" assumption is a bad question. Am I right?"_. Meh... it's not a _good_ question definitely, but it's not appalling either. Downvote if you don't think enough effort has been put in.

Comment: @Seth Well, I can understand the question myself. But the question the mindset feels like "I have this problem, solve it for me". It doesn't seem he tried anything. And the guidelines to ask say we should try and solve our problems before posting. And it was rather obvious that he had to use the group by clause, but He never mentioned he was having problems with it, or such.

Comment: @Dzyann Yes, I see that. Downvotes are for when you feel like that ;)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards so you think the best thing to do is just a downvote? I am asking too because I have seen many cases just like the one in this question and the OP was heavily downvoted and such. His question has a lot of information, but nothing on what he did to solve his problem.

Comment: @Seth would it be foolish to downvote now?

Comment: @Dzyann No... I can't see a reason why it would be.

Comment: @Seth well I wouldn't want to come as aggressive. I mean he got his question answered and all, and no one down-voted him before. Even the reason would seem strange because he got his answer.

Comment: @Dzyann The internet is a big place. You don't have time to worry about what others think ;-) Some will always agree with you, others will always disagree. It's up to you. I personally try to be sparing in my downvotes, but that's just me.

Comment: Does it really matter what he tried? I don't see how including some invalid attempt would add anything except noise.

Comment: My advice would be to vote often; be it up or down. Establish a set of rules, that _you_ believe are fair and stick to them. If you believe that not enough research effort has been put in, then by all means downvote. Don't worry about it. If you are worried then maybe it's an indicator that you don't believe you should in this situation.

Comment: @Seth others even up-voted it, so that is why I feel is confusing. And he is not a new user, so he should know better. I got down-voted in this question, and I am not sure why. Thanks! I think I got my doubt answered, what should I do with this question?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences for how voting works on meta.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards well I was sure it was a wrong question from the FAQ and such. I just didn't know what the best thing to do was. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinSmith I have seen plenty of questions like his, and I guess depending on who reads get heavily down-voted or not. And if you read the FAQ it says you should try and solve your problem by yourself first. So that is why I was asking.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Yes I know that it means they don't agree with me. But I would have liked some input on why. Is wrong to ask something like I asked?

Comment: No... maybe someone just didn't think that the person in the question did anything wrong. Maybe they think that they did and that you don't need to ask. No idea :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards and Seth comments have been very helpful to me. So what should I do about my question? I can delete it since no one has answered, but doesn't feel right.

Comment: @Dzyann - There are loads of highly voted questions on Stack Overflow that just state a problem and don't show research. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git). As long as the problem statement is clear and includes information about any potential solutions the OP may have come across but discarded as unsuitable that is enough IMO. Though if the tone of the question is "I want X" rather than "How do I do X" that will often not go down well.

Comment: @MartinSmith I am just trying to understand well the rules of the site. According to the site you should do research. Many times the OP does exactly the same that in the question I am referring to and it gets a ton of down-votes. This particular question didn't have much views, I think because of the way it was written. So maybe if it would have gotten more attention it would have been down-voted. I think it depends a lot on who checks the question. Whats more I believe that the OP could have solved his problem by himself if he would have tried, but that is just my thought.

Comment: @MartinSmith my main objective with asking this question, wasn't to get the OP question down-voted, I saw it long ago and I have been thinking what was the right thing to do in cases like that. In the end I decided to ask. And I found Seth and Ben comments very useful to solve my issue. And I appreciate your point of view too. I think luck plays a big role on how your question is received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarise everything said in the comments; it's essentially your decision. Do what you think is correct.

The OP has a good (and accepted) answer.. So obviously someone understood enough to post a good answer.

If you don't think enough effort has been put in then you can downvote; if you think it's warranted. Establish a set of rules, that you believe are fair and stick to them. If you believe that not enough research effort has been put in, then by all means downvote. Don't worry about it.

If you are worried then maybe it's an indicator that you don't believe you should in this situation. Some will always agree with you, others will always disagree. It's up to you.